# I want to make a aspect which will take effect when i add a annotation on the type and method,but failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop

I want to make a aspect which will  take effect when i add a annotation on the type and method.
the Aspect class:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class ActionUnlockAspect {
    @Before("@target(com.example.demo.aspect.ActionUnlockCheck)||@annotation(com.example.demo.aspect.ActionUnlockCheck)")
    public void check(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
         //do something...
    }

}
```

annotation class

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Repeatable(ActionUnlockChecks.class)
public @interface ActionUnlockCheck {
    int actionType();
}
```

I use springboot version 2.1.7.RELEASE.
When i start the springboot project,error occur.here is the stacktrace:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:660) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ClassLoaderAwareGeneratorStrategy.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:585) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:57) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206) ~[spring-aop-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Whether to add related dependencies,  spring-boot-starter-aop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your pointcut is too global. As `@target()` can only be evaluated during runtime, as is documented, the aspect is basically applied to all classes. One way is to use `@within()` instead. If that does not work, you can also add something like `... && within(my.own.app..*)` in order to limit the aspect scope.

Comment: The way to thank people on SO is to mark correct answers as accepted (click on the grey checkmark beside the answer, making it green) and to upvote comments or answers if they are helpful. You need to have a few reputation points first before you can upvote, though.